# pandas groupby week and rolling

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a dataframe like this:

```
dfx=pd.DataFrame({"name":["bag","bag","bag","phone","phone","phone"],'date':["2022-11-14 00:00:00","2022-11-21 00:00:00","2022-11-28 00:00:00","2022-11-14 00:00:00","2022-11-21 00:00:00","2022-11-28 00:00:00"],"view":[80,90,100,200,400,450]})
'''
    name                 date  view
0    bag  2022-11-14 00:00:00    80
1    bag  2022-11-21 00:00:00    90
2    bag  2022-11-28 00:00:00   100
3  phone  2022-11-14 00:00:00   200
4  phone  2022-11-21 00:00:00   400
5  phone  2022-11-28 00:00:00   450
'''
```

I would like to group by name and week and get rolling views by week. Expected output:

```
name  one_week_view  two_weeks_view  three_weeks_wiew
bag   80             170              270  
phone 200            600              1050
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you already have weekly data, you could use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
(dfx.pivot(index='name', columns='date', values='view')
    .cumsum(axis=1)
    .set_axis(['one_week_view', 'two_weeks_view', 'three_weeks_view'], axis=1)
 )
```

Output:

```
       one_week_view  two_weeks_view  three_weeks_view
name                                                  
bag               80             170               270
phone            200             600              1050
```